# How to create a text file in a folder on the desktop

Tags: c++, save, ofstream

I have a problem in my project. There is a project folder on my desktop. I want to create a text file and write something include this text file. That is my code:

`ofstream example("/Users/sample/Desktop/save.txt");`

But I want to it could been run the other mac. I don't know what I should write addres for save.txt.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So, you want the "right way" to obtain the path to the desktop, correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file and write some text to it is simple, here is a sample code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main() 
   {
      std::ofstream o("/Users/sample/Desktop/save.txt");

      o << "Hello, World\n" << std::endl;

      return 0;
   }
```

I hope that answers your question but I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, If not please add the details correctly of what you are trying to acheive.

[Update]: 
Okay I guess the comment clears the problem.
Your real question is, ***You want to save the file in the desktop of the user who is playing the game.  So getting the path of the current user's desktop is the problem.***

I am not sure if there is an portable way to get desktop path but it can be done in following ways:

***In Windows:***
Using the **[SHGetSpecialFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28VS.85%29.aspx)** function.

*Sample code:*

```
char saveLocation[MAX_PATH] = {0};

SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, saveLocation, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);

//Now saveLocation contains the path to the desktop
//Append your file name to it
strcat(saveLocation,"\\save.txt");

ofstream o(saveLocation);
```

***In Linux:***
By using environment variables $HOME

*sample code:*

```
string path(getenv("HOME"));
path += "/Desktop/save.txt";
ofstream o(path);
```

Comment: Based on "but ı want to it could been run the other mac.ı don't know what ı should write addres for save.txt.can anyone help me?" I think OP knows how to write to a text file and wants a portable way to obtain the desktop path.

Comment: @Xeo: What's a "portable desktop"? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Where do I say anything about a portable desktop? - "a portable way to obtain the desktop path"

Comment: @Xeo: sorry, it was a joke... the entire idea of obtaining the path presumes that there is a path to be found in the first place, so it sort of presumes the existence of a desktop, which I dubbed the "portable desktop". Never mind though!

Comment: well the problem is that it will compile only in comp with samp user , but i want to inside my project so that it couldve compiled in any comp, it's kind of savegame file.. i hope its clearer now

Comment: ı wrote your updated answer but it gives error "use of undeclerad identifier [MAX_PATH]  " how can ı solve this error.Also which library can ı use??

Comment: @muhammedkasva: MAX_PATH is a macro which defines maximum range of the path, You can keep it something like `#define MAX_PATH 256`

Comment: well ı did it is fixed.at now the same error for "CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY"

Comment: Did you check the msdn link i added to SHGetSpecialFolderPath() function? You need to include `Shlobj.h` and link to library `Shell32.lib`, please read that link.

Comment: ı use xcode 4. ı tried to d but it gives error.can you  tell me step b step

Comment: @muhammedkasva: How can you use Windows functions on Mac book?

Comment: ı said that macbook in the beginning.ı thought you tell this code according to macosx

Comment: @muhammedkasva: Mac & Windows are two different OS you cannot use functions from Windows library on Mac simply because Mac won't use those libraries. Linux code works on Mac because the underneath Mac OS uses Linux. You should use the Linux code sample I gave in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rules defining where-you-should-save-file vary from platform to platform. One option would be to have it part of your compile script (that is you #define SAVEGAME_PATH as part of your compilation configuration), and thus your code itself remain more platform-agnostic.

The alternative is to find a save-data-management library that is already designed to be ported across different platforms. Whether it'd be a C or C++ or whatever-binary-interoperable library then no longer matters.

Just don't expect that to be part of C++ (the language).

Answer (score -1):

if you want your program to run across platform,you'd better use the
relative path.
eg.  "./output.txt",or better “GetSystemDirectory()”to obtain the system
directory  to create a file,and then you could write or read the file 
with the same path..