# Create a zero byte file in specific directory

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");


   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

the above programs will create a file . i need that file needs to be placed in specific directory. please help

Comment: Do the file and directory need to be hard coded? Can you pass them as command line arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477568/how-to-create-text-file-in-c

Comment: @sandeep The command line arguments are passed as the second argument to `main()`. Please read a C book of choice for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add path into the parameter of `fopen()`.

```
fp = fopen ("/path/to/file.txt", "w+");
```